# eclipse ant integration and code formatting

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have configured Eclipse to use ant for doing the builds by setting the builders in project properties to point to the ant build script.
The build goes thru fine. However in my eclipse project I have not imported the required jars as a part of the project settings. All of this is done in ant's build.xml.

So in the java files, I get red squiglly lines for all the import packages which eclipse is not able to resolve.

How do I make these squiglly lines go away? One way is to import the required jars in eclipse, but then I am maintaining the project at two places, ant build.xml and eclipse

Comment: Can you show us the part of `build.xml` that does this?

Comment: <property name="THIRD_PARTY" location="../ThirdParty"/>
 <path id="Toolkit.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${THIRD_PARTY}/jars">
   <include name = "**/*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
 </path>
The thirdparty jars are outside of the folder managed by eclipse, this is because the thirdparty jars are shared with other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to Project Properties/Build Path and enter the jars you rely on there.

Comment: Yeah, you only need to give the path to the jars that is used by Ant; you don't need to copy them so there isn't really much overhead.

Comment: well the problem is that the build path does not accept relative paths, so I can add it but if someone else takes the code from source control, because the build path stores absolute path, they need to fix the path. The third party jars are in a folder outside the folder managed by eclipse i.e outside the folder that contains the .classpath file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage your dependencies. If you configure it properly, you will only be defining the jars in one place but both Eclipse and Ant will be able to see them. The eclipse plug-in is [IvyDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/).